# SO question page markup flawed in Opera browser

Tags: bug

The SO question page markup is flawed in Opera browser. As you can see on the screenshot, comments are overflowed with the `Careers` block. This is with `Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.11`

**upd** The bug shows up occasionally, not in every question, but still quite often. Actually it is not always reproduced in the same question. Probably depends on the contents.

[image: flawed markup]

Comment: Which question?

Comment: @ hims056, Umm.. It's a bug, not a question, as you can see from the tag. As far as I got it this is the way bugs are posted. Am I wrong?

Comment: Umm.. Is this bug comes in every question or in just a single question?

Comment: @ hims056, sorry a bit of misunderstanding here =). It shows up occasionally, not in every question, but quite often.

Comment: Surely the *markup* is the same in every browser...

Comment: @AakashM Don't count on it. Server-side tech and CSS styles can be used to target markup at specific browsers, of course. ;)

Comment: as far as I can tell, Opera 9.80 isn't listed here: [Which browsers are officially supported?...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/165773)

Comment: @gnat It's Opera 12.11, as indicated at the end of the UA. The 9.80 is there either for compatibility reasons or for triggering a wave of suicides among the guys in charge of writing UA parsers.